# HDP 2.6.5 on Windows 10 Hyper-v

Tags: hadoop, windows-10, cloudera, hyper-v, hdp

I am trying to run HDP 2.6.5 on Windows 10 laptop using Hyper V Manager. I downloaded the VirtualBox version and extracted the .vmdk and converted it to .vhd file using VirtualBox software.

```
 & 'C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe' clonehd .\HDP-2.6.5.vmdk .\HDP-2.6.5.vhdx -format VHD
```

I tried to load the vhd using Hyperv Gen1 VM with 8GB initial memory (dynamic) and 4 Virtual processors. My laptop has 32G RAM and an i7 processor.

[image]

I am getting below boot error when starting the VM.

[image]

I used below blogs as reference:

> https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/robinlester/2016/07/26/getting-started-with-hortonworks-2-4-in-hyper-v/
>   https://blog.pythian.com/converting-hortonworks-sandbox-run-hyper-v/

Both of these blogs are using HDP 2.4 for setup and I am using HDP 2.6.5 Sandbox, couldn't find HDP 2.4 archive download.

Does this version work on Hyper V, any suggestions ?

Comment: I think HDP 2.6 is end of life. Is there not a 3.x one? If not, you can use Vagrant and Hortonworks Ansible repo to quickly setup your own HDP cluster

Answer (score 0):

> Entering emergency mode. Exit the shell to continue.

Well dear i solved same problem but with physical machine in HDP 3.x.

i use bootable usb and use this command:

```
xfs_repair -v -L /dev/dm-0
```

Then i restart the machine.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue with CentOS on UTM, fixed it with

```
xfs_repair -L /dev/mapper/centos-root
```

A bit more info here: https://isbyr.com/centos-repair-corrupt-boot-drive/